# how to use pdf.js without defining pdf.worker location

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I meet a problem when using pdf.js to view pdf. The problem comes from the 
PDFJS.workerSrc setting. Is that possible to include the pdf.worker.js in 
header, like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./../jsfiles/pdf.worker.js"></script>
```

and not using

```
PDFJS.workerSrc = './../jsfiles/pdf.worker.js';
```

is that possible for that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js#building-pdfjs):

> In order to bundle all `src/` files into two production scripts and build the generic viewer, run:
>
> ```
> $ gulp generic
> ```
>
> This will generate `pdf.js` and `pdf.worker.js` in the `build/generic/build/` directory. Both scripts are needed but only `pdf.js` needs to be included since `pdf.worker.js` will be loaded by `pdf.js`. The PDF.js files are large and should be minified for production.

This means that you only need to add the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pdf.js"></script>
```

*Remember that all files generated should located in the same directory as `pdf.js`*